# how do I turn this into a custom excel function?

Tags: c#, excel

I have the following C# code, which pulls data from a database & populates cell A1 w/ the data when Excel loads. How do I turn this into a custom function, whereby the field would populate when the user types in the formula (ie '=getMyData("mycustominput")'), rather than when excel loads?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; 

namespace custom_excel
{
public partial class ThisAddIn
{

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet);
        Excel.Range firstRow = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1", missing);
        firstRow.EntireRow.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, System.Type.Missing);
        Excel.Range newFirstRow = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1", missing);

        string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=test;Uid=name;password=password";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT field_value FROM customers LIMIT 1";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
             newFirstRow.Value2 = reader["field_value"].ToString();
        }

    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going out on a limb here, but have you looked at [ExcelDNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/)?  It sounds like it might work for what you are trying to do.

There is also [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/12/01/273127.aspx) somewhat older article from Eric Carter that might be of use, which uses an automation add-in.  It appears you can do it without any 3rd party libraries.